# Format JsonArray php

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

i would like to format it this way but i am unable to
 at the moment it looks like this:

```
    {"success":true,"user":"tom","gender":"male","age":"2"}
{"success":true,"user":"anna","gender":"female","age":"3"}
```

but it should look like this

```
  {
      "result":[ 
                 {"success":true,"user":"tom","gender":"male"},
                 {"success":true,"user":"anna","gender":"female"}
               ]
    }
```

this is my code

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
       $user= $row["user"];
       $gender= $row["gender"];

       $response["user"] = $user;
       $response["gender"] = $gender;
       $response["success"] = true;

       echo json_encode($response); 

     }
   }
```

Comment: I fail to see how your examples and your code are related.

Comment: Question is fine as is, and makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
       $user= $row["user"];
       $gender= $row["gender"];

       $response['result'][] = [
           'user' => $user,
           'gender' => $gender,
           'success' => true
       ];

     }
     echo json_encode($response);
   }
```

You were formatting it on each loop, which will output entirely separate sets of JSON.

Comment: thank you so much i have been stuck at this for hours really appreciate your answer :) :)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, then please mark it as such by checking the tick below the voting buttons when it becomes available.